Use remote variables in local bash script via SSH
I am trying to process a bash script on a local machine but where some of the variables are needed from a remote machine (on the same LAN) via SSH.  Here's where I've go to s far, but it is getting the variabales where I'm stuck. How to I script to login via SSH to retrieve the variables shown below.  Many thanks.
     #!/bin/sh

 MAX_TEMP_CPU=80
 MAX_TEMP_24=60
 MAX_TEMP_5=60

 # Email settings (mail envelope) #
 FROM_ADDRESS="someaddress"
 TO_NAME="name"
 TO_ADDRESS="address"

 # Email credentials #
 USERNAME="email"
 PASSWORD="password"

 # Server settings #
 SMTP="smtp.gmail.com"
 PORT="465"

 # FROM Name in email #
 FROM_NAME="Router $(nvram get productid)"

 # set environment PATH to system binaries #
 export PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:$PATH


 # get these variables from remote server via SSH i.e., ssh user@IPaddress password #

 wifi24_status=$(nvram get wl0_ifname)
 wifi5_status=$(nvram get wl1_ifname)

 cpu_temp=$(cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp | sed 's/[^0-9]//g' | awk '{print int( $1 / 1000 +0.5)}')
 wifi24_temp=$(wl -i $wifi24_status phy_tempsense | awk '{print int($1 / 2 + 20 +0.5)}')
 wifi5_temp=$(wl -i $wifi5_status phy_tempsense | awk '{print int($1 / 2 + 20 +0.5)}')

 # end remote server shell connection #


 if [ $cpu_temp -gt $MAX_TEMP_CPU -o $wifi24_temp -gt $MAX_TEMP_24 -o $wifi5_temp -gt $MAX_TEMP_5 ]; then
  msg="Temperature too hot, CPU: $cpu_temp/$MAX_TEMP_CPU DegC 2.4Ghz wifi: $wifi24_temp/$MAX_TEMP_24 DegC 5Ghz wifi: $wifi5_temp/$MAX_TEMP_5 DegC"

# notify Syslog of the event
#logger $msg

# assemble the message
echo "From: \"$FROM_NAME\" <$FROM_ADDRESS>" > /tmp/mail.txt
echo "To: \"$TO_NAME\" <$TO_ADDRESS>" >> /tmp/mail.txt
echo "Subject: $msg" >> /tmp/mail.txt
echo "Date: $(date -R)" >> /tmp/mail.txt
echo "" >> /tmp/mail.txt
echo "--- " >> /tmp/mail.txt
echo "Your friendly home router $(nvram get productid)." >> /tmp/mail.txt

# send with curl
curl --url smtps://$SMTP:$PORT \
--mail-from "$FROM_ADDRESS" --mail-rcpt "$TO_ADDRESS" \
--upload-file /tmp/mail.txt \
--ssl-reqd \
--user "$USERNAME:$PASSWORD"

# remove temp file
rm /tmp/mail.txt
fi


I would try something like this for your script running on a local machine gathering data from a remote machine:
wifi24_status=`ssh "user@${dest_server}" "nvram get wl0_ifname"`
wifi5_status=`ssh "user@${dest_server}" "nvram get wl1_ifname"`
cpu_temp=`ssh "user@${dest_server}" "cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp | sed 's/[^0-9]//g' | awk '{print int( $1 / 1000 +0.5)}'"`

Note: Setup ssh passwordless entry between servers. More on that here: https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/passwordless-ssh

Thank you.  How would i add the password to each entry.  Its on a local network and am happy to have plain test for the password.

It is better to group all the remote commands into a single ssh session. If you have multiple values to return to the ssh caller, then stream them all with one of the IFS characters. Either read -r wifi24_status wifi5_status cpu_temp < <(ssh ...) as fields. Or use a record delimiter which is usually LF but can be NULL, { read -r wifi24_status; read -r wifi5_status; read -rcpu_temp; } < <(ssh ...). Either one works. The later allow use of NULL-delimited value and transfer of content with any other special character including newlines.

You could take a look at sshpass instead of ssh, but be aware of security issues when passing passwords as plaintext (both command line and scripted).
